serving webapp as plain text - using Flask + uWSGI
i cannot figure out why starting my webapp using uwsgi does not return a normal website, but just a plain text response.
I am using flask websocket, and gevent.

starting the app manually using simple "python start.py" works perfectly normal.
Changing my async_mode to "gevent_uwsgi" and staring using uwsgi configuration i get a plain text response in browser:

Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36378

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Driver Control</title>

.....and the rest of my index.html as text.

My nginx rev.proxy is configured to pass anything on port 80 to port 5000 where uwsgi is expecting calls
Here is my configuration file:
[uwsgi]
env=XILINX_XRT=/usr
uid=root
gid=root
wsgi-file=start.py
module=start
callable=app
master=true
processes=1
workers=2
enable-threads=true
emperor-tyrant=true
protocol=http
gevent=1000
socket=:5000
vacuum=true
virtualenv = /usr/local/share/pynq-venv/
#pythonpath = /home/xilinx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
pythonpath = /usr/local/share/pynq-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages

This is running on xilinx version of linux based on ubuntu 20.04
I have been searching but i cannot find anyone having the same issue.
